# Travel to Gibraltar in October 2021 as an EU national

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, eu, brexit, gibraltar

I'm an EU (Romanian, so non-Schengen) citizen and I will travel to Gibraltar from Spain in mid October 2021.

My question is: can I enter Gibraltar with my national ID card or do I need a passport for this event?

Comment: Note that I have deleted my answer as there are pending changes for entry into the UK from 1st of October and I don't yet know if they apply to Gibraltar.

Comment: All sources I have found say that entry into Gibraltar is possible with an EU ID card and make no reference to the changes for the UK from 01/10, but I'm not sure whether that's because it won't change or because the pages haven't been updated. However, I haven't found any document which explicitly states that the new UK rules from 01/10 don't apply in Gibraltar. I sent an e-mail to the Gibraltar borders agency for clarification.

Comment: As I understand it, Gibraltar will become part of the Schengen area, and is not part of UK, it is a British Overseas Territory.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, Gibraltar will become sort-of-kind-of part of the Schengen Area, but it's still unclear when that will happen and exactly what will happen. And even if Gibraltar is not part of the UK, as a UK dependency, lots of things have changed due to Brexit. It's unclear if that change (EU ID cards no longer valid in the UK) only applies to the UK itself or if that may trickle down to Gibraltar (lots of things have changed for people from Gibraltar when it comes to their relationship with the EU, the reverse can be true as well).

Comment: Gibraltar has seperate immigration laws. Negotiations are still underway: [Preparatory Work for UK/EU Treaty Negotiations - 619/2021](https://www.gibraltar.gov.gi/press-releases/preparatory-work-for-ukeu-treaty-negotiations-6192021-7196). Since a greater amount of their workforce comes from Spain (who would then require a passport), one can assume that the UK passport requirement does not apply to Gibraltar since they make no meantion of this on their main government site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

20 October 2021 status:

Just returned from this trip, the **passport isn't mandatory**, as an **EU citizen** I was able to enter Gibraltar without passport, **one can enter with their national ID**. I must mention that it was a half-day trip so I didn't have to stay overnight, book a hotel or other paperwork.