# Traveling to Gibraltar from Spain as an EU citizen. Is a passport required?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, europe, brexit, gibraltar

I have found a [similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168514/travel-to-gibraltar-in-october-2021-as-an-eu-national?newreg=4655e4437a614708a4294b930b6b4dff) posted here but without clear answers.

So this is my issue too. It is clear that after October 1st 2021 if one wants to travel to United Kingdom as an EU citizen you need a valid passport, it's not permitted anymore with the national ID.

My plan is to visit Gibraltar this month entering on ground from Spain. Gibraltar is part of UK but still has some different regulations.  If I understand right it is part of the Schengen area in a way that UK never was, so maybe there are different rules for crossing the border too.

To sum up, my question is do I need a passport to enter Gibraltar as EU citizen coming from Spain, or is it still acceptable to enter with my national ID?

Comment: http://www.visitgibraltar.gi/faqs *Passports are required by all visitors to Gibraltar, except EU nationals who are in possession of a valid national identity card.*

Comment: Yes, I went to Gibraltar from Cádiz when the UK was in the EU and I had to show my UK passport to get in.

Comment: @Tom what connection is between the question and your answer?  OP asks about rules after October 1st

Answer (score 8):

Gibraltar is an [Overseas Territory of the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Overseas_Territories) and has its own immigration laws.

For short term visits, nothing has changed for EU citizens.

> [Do I need a visa to enter Gibraltar?](http://www.visitgibraltar.gi/faqs#tab10)
> Passports are required by all visitors to Gibraltar, **except EU nationals who are in possession of a valid national identity card**.  All other nationals require a passport or other recognised travel document.
> ...

There are negotiations underway with the goal that Gibraltar will become a part of the Schengen Area, but have not yet been completed.

- [2021-09-01: Preparatory Work for UK/EU Treaty Negotiations - 619/2021](https://www.gibraltar.gov.gi/press-releases/preparatory-work-for-ukeu-treaty-negotiations-6192021-7196)

Answer (score 0):

I did this trip two weeks ago, using my ID card. Gibraltar still accepted national ID cards in September.

Gibraltar is not yet part of the Schengen Area, but will be included and the border control is to be abolished in the future.

I tried to find something about your question on the official government websites, but at some places it says to bring a passport and on others it says a passport or ID is required.

I think that if IDs were no longer allowed, there would be a specific warning about this. Also, there is a warning that when travelling from Gibraltar to the UK by air, you now need to have a passport, which also probably wouldn't be there if you needed a passport to enter Gibraltar in the first place.

Comment: The core of the question is wether the changes in UK immigration laws on October 1st also apply to Gibraltar or not. It probably does not help OP to know what Gibraltar accepted two weeks ago.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo exactly